# Почему такой скрипт не работает ? Не пойму где ошибка

Tags: javascript, циклы, переменные, сравнение

Исходная задача:
Напишите цикл, который предлагает prompt ввести число, большее 100. Если посетитель ввёл другое число – попросить ввести ещё раз, и так далее.

Цикл должен спрашивать число пока либо посетитель не введёт число, большее 100, либо не нажмёт кнопку Отмена (ESC).

Предполагается, что посетитель вводит только числа. Предусматривать обработку нечисловых строк в этой задаче необязательно.
Мой скрипт:

```
let num;

while (true) {
let num = prompt("Введите число большее 100",'');

if ( num<=100 ){
alert('Попробуйте ввести заново');
} 
else if( num>100||num == null )break;
}

    alert("Вы ввели подходящее число");
```

Данный скрипт не срабатывает , если нажать Отмена. Но ведь при нажатии Отмена, как я понимаю, num == null, результат почему-то все равно получается: Введите число большее 100

Может кто-то разъяснить, что не так делаю ?

Comment: Понимаю , что в решении данной задачи лучше использовать цикл do ...  while , но сейчас не о том спрашиваю и хотел бы понять почему в такой версии код работает не верно.

Comment: `console.log( Number(null) ); // 0` при сравнении `null <= 100`, js пытается привести оба операнда к примитивному значению... Это равносильно `0 <= 100`

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
null < 100   //  true При сравнении значений разных типов JavaScript приводит каждое из них к числу.
```

Можно перенести сравнение с (else if)  выше  в условие (if) для того чтобы проверить в первую очередь нажал ли клиент "Отмену"(null)

```
 while (true) {
  let num = prompt('Введите число больше 100', '');
  if (num !== null && num <= 100  ) { 
    alert('Попробуйте ввести заново');
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей в ваш ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Благодарю.  Такой вариант будет понагляднее.